# Convert auto generated subtitle to srt format with youtube-dl

Tags: conversion, subtitles, youtube-dl

I want to download generated subtitle from youtube and convert it to srt format using command `youtube-dl --write-auto-sub --sub-lang en --convert-subs=srt --skip-download <URL>` it just output .vtt file and doesn't convert it to srt.

But when `--skip-download` is removed, then it would download the video, the vtt file, then finally convert vtt to srt.

Is there any way to download only vtt file then convert it to srt without downloading the video?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the reason is that ffmpeg, used behind the scenes in this process, does not handle recoding requests like "ffmpeg.exe -i path.vtt path.vtt.srt" directly. It needs a stream to the file, and for that it needs a video file.

At least, such request does not work for me, and reports the absence of a stream, despite the presence of similar examples on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I made a very simple command line tool to convert vtt to srt, it works via just very simple text processing (no lexical analysis or tokens used) and it works only for Youtube's automaticaly transcribed subtitles, for a text like this:

> WEBVTT Kind: captions Language: en
>
> 00:00:01.740 --> 00:00:05.030 align:start position:0%
> nothing<00:00:02.700> is<00:00:03.179> impossible...

You can download it in ZIP file here: http://pececko.szm.com/ @ `VTT to SRT`. I am not planning to update it, so please consider this code as public domain. I Hope this can be useful for somebody.

```
// C program to convert subtitles from VTT file to SRT file
// public domain
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINELEN 32767

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    FILE* fh;
    char filein[MAXLINELEN]; // = "test.vtt"
    char fileout[MAXLINELEN]; // = "test.srt"
    int i=0, j=0, k=0, l=0, m=0, pos=0;
    //float r=0;
    char **arr; // array of pointers to lines loaded to memory from file
    char *buffer, *line, *ptr;
    long numbytes;
    int erase=0, previousline=0; // booleans
    fputs("Convert Youtube's Autotranscribed VTT to SRT [build 2023-06-22]\nConverts .vtt files from youtube to .srt files.\nUsage: vtttosrt.exe [sourcesubtitles.vtt] [targetsubtitles.srt]\nPress Ctrl+C to abort.\n", stdout);
    if (argc>1){
        strcpy(filein, argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("Enter input filename (*.vtt) :");
        fgets (filein, MAXLINELEN, stdin);
        filein[strlen(filein) - 1] = '\0';
    }
    k = strlen(filein);
    if (!k) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (k<=3 || (strstr(&filein[k-4],".vtt") == NULL)) {
        strcat(filein,".vtt"); //append missing extension
    }

    fh = fopen(filein, "r"); // Opening file in reading mode
    if (fh==NULL) {
        printf("File %s not found.\n",filein);
        return 1;
    }
 
    //printf("Loading file %s\n", filein);
    fseek(fh, 0L, SEEK_END);
    numbytes = ftell(fh); // Get the number of bytes
    fseek(fh, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = (char*)calloc(numbytes, sizeof(char)); 
    if(buffer == NULL) {
        fclose(fh);
        return 1;
    }
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), numbytes, fh);
    fclose(fh);
    //printf("filesize is %d Bytes:\n%s\n",numbytes,buffer);

    arr = (char**)calloc(numbytes/4, sizeof(char));
    if(arr == NULL) {
        free(buffer);
        return 1;
    }
    pos=1;
    arr[0] = &buffer[0];
    for (i=0; i<numbytes; i++) {
        if (buffer[i]=='\n') {
            buffer[i]='\0';
            arr[pos++]=&buffer[i+1];
        }
    }
    //printf("number of lines in file = %d\n",pos); return 0;
    //now we will remove <timestamps> and align+position
    j=0;
    for (i=0; i<pos; i++) {
        line=arr[i];
        if (strlen(line)>1){ // if not empty line
            arr[j]=arr[i];
            if (NULL != (ptr=strstr(line," --> "))) { // if timing line
                ptr[17] = '\0'; //strip the text "align:start position:0%"
                l = strlen(line);
                for (m=0; m<=l; m++) {
                    if (line[m]=='.') {
                        line[m]=',';
                    }
                }
            } else { //else subtitle line
                l = strlen(line);
                k = 0;
                erase=0; // boolean: keep or erase text in between <...>
                for (m=0; m<=l; m++){
                    if (line[m]=='<') {erase=1;}
                    else if (line[m]=='>') {erase=0;}
                        else if (!erase) {
                            line[k++] = line[m];
                        }
                }
            }
            //printf("%d:%d:%d: %s\n",i,j, strlen(line), line);
            j++;
        } // else {skip empty line.}
    }
    pos=j;
    //printf("exluding empty lines = %d\nResult:\n",pos); for (i=0; i<pos; i++) {printf("%d:%d: %s\n",i, strlen(line), arr[i]);} return 0;

    // now we will remove duplicate textlines:
    i=0;
    while ((NULL == strstr(arr[i]," --> ")) && (i<pos)){
        i++;
    };// seek to the first timeline
    line = arr[0] = arr[i]; // pointer to first time line
    i++;
    j=1;
    for (; i<pos; i++) {
        ptr=strstr(arr[i]," --> ");
        erase = (strcmp(arr[i],line)==0); // 0==are equals.
        if (ptr == NULL && erase) { // if this textline and duplicate of previous textline
            continue;
        }
        // now to treat timelines and new textlines:
        if (ptr == NULL) { // if isnt timeline
            line = arr[i]; // its new textline
        }
        arr[j] = arr[i];
        j++;
        //printf("%d:%d: %s\n",i, strlen(line), arr[i]);
    }
    pos = j;
    //printf("without duplicate textlines=%d\nResult:\n",pos); for (i=0; i<pos; i++) {printf("%d:%d: %s\n",i, strlen(arr[i]), arr[i]);} return 0;

    // now we will remove duplicate timelines:
    previousline=0; // previous line was 0=textline, 1=timeline
    j=1;
    for (i=1; i<pos; i++) {
        ptr=strstr(arr[i]," --> ");
        if (previousline==1 || ptr==NULL){ // keep this, if previous was textline or this is textline
            arr[j]=arr[i];
            j++;
        } //else { this is second timeline, skip it }
        previousline = (ptr!=NULL)?1:0;
        //printf("%d:%d: %s\n",i, strlen(line), arr[i]);
    }
    pos = j;
    //printf("without duplicate timelines=%d\nResult:\n",pos); for (i=0; i<pos; i++) {printf("%d:%d: %s\n",i, strlen(arr[i]), arr[i]);} return 0;
    printf("Subtitles from file %s loaded.\n", filein);
    
    //create .srt file
    if (argc==3) {
        strcpy(fileout, argv[2]);
    } else {
        k=strlen(filein);
        filein[k-3]='s';filein[k-2]='r';filein[k-1]='t';
        printf("Enter output filename (default: %s) : ",filein);
        fgets (fileout, MAXLINELEN, stdin);
        fileout[strlen(fileout) - 1] = '\0';
    }
    k = strlen(fileout);
    if (k==0) {
        strcpy(fileout, filein); // use default output filename.srt
        k=strlen(fileout);
    }
    if (k<=3 || (strstr(&fileout[k-4],".srt") == NULL)) { // if .srt extension omitted
        strcat(fileout,".srt"); //append missing extension
    }
    fh = fopen(fileout, "w"); // create new file
    if (fh==NULL) {
        printf("File creating error. Sending the result to stdout.\n");
        fh=stdout;
    }

    //find first timeline
    i=0;
    while (!strstr(arr[i]," --> ") && (i<pos)) {
        i++;
    }
    j=1;
    while (i<pos){
        ptr = strstr(arr[i]," --> "); // NULL~textline
        if (ptr) { //if timeline
            fprintf(fh,"%d\n%s\n",j,arr[i]);
            j++;
        } else {
            fprintf(fh,"%s\n\n",arr[i]);
        }
        i++;
        //printf("%d:%d: %s\n",i, stlen(arr[i]), arr[i]);
    }
    if (fh!=stdout) {
        fclose(fh);
    }
    printf("Subtitles exported to %s.\n",fileout);
    free(arr);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```